# Android WebView javascript support

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-chrome, webview

I am using Android's built in WebView to show something to the user. I also insert custom javacsript to the page user is is viewing, since it's rather complicated javascript (lets call it userscript, because it acts like you are using for an example Chrome's a userscript on specific page only) Im interested what are the differences in Chromes WebView in different devices?

I guess they are using stock "browser" rendering, but what about javascript support, css3 support etc. on different devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be clear.

WebView on Android is actually a version of WebKit customised for the Android platform. It's not a version of Chrome.

Chrome for Android stays up to date as much as possible with desktop chrome.

On iOS I believe the WebView is a single core version of the Safari browser so has some differences.

Chrome for iOS uses this WebView to display web content.

Regarding support best thing to do it look at sites such as http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Android WebView is the same as the "Android Stock Browser" that exists on many Android phones (but is oddly unavailable in Google's Nexus devices).  This is true for rendering, JavaScript, etc.  When you're looking at a site such as http://caniuse.com, the "Android" column is what you're looking for, not the "Chrome" column.

Unfortunately, testing on Chrome bears almost no relation to using a WebView on Android.  Google has stated that they are working on a new WebView component that would be part of Chrome. I asked Google representatives directly when this would be available at PhoneGap Day last month, but all they could say is "it's coming".